# How to add text field in front of label in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

Can you please tell me how to add text field in front of label in jquery mobile .[image]

There is two different types of text field in this image.How to implement this?

Comment: How to add square button in jquery mobile

Comment: square buttons or text input?

Comment: Square buttons i did it..now only text field

Comment: this will help you, http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/textinputs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just you have to copy simple code to your website...

**For input box:-**

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
         <label for="text-12">Text input:</label>
         <input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="text">
    </div>
```

**For textarea:-**

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="textarea-12">Textarea:</label>
        <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="textarea-12" id="textarea-12"></textarea>
    </div>
```

Keep that in mind the value of `for=""` and `id=""` of input box should be same...

For more details check out:- http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/demos/widgets/textinputs/

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to add textfield

```
<label for="basic">Text Input:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="basic" value=""  />
```

Ref this docs to know more informations about JQM

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/forms/textinputs/